# Keep multiple parameters on one line in scalafmt

Tags: scalafmt

I want Scalafmt to accept this kind of formatting:

```scala
val result = longMethodName(
  a, b, c, d)
```

But currently it gets turned into:

```scala
val result = longMethodName(
  a,
  b,
  c,
  d)
```

When the parameters are short the first form is much more pleasing. Is there an option to allow it?